# XAMPP SSL Issue on Mac OS X

Tags: php, ssl, xampp

I have XAMPP installed on Mac OS X and am having an issue running this code

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("https://extensions.bolt.cm/list.json");
?>
```

I get the following error

> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in index.php on line 2

mod_ssl is loaded and OpenSSL is enabled

allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include are both on

I have seen other threads talk about uncommenting the extension=php_openssl.dll line in the php.ini file, but that appears to be for Windows. If there is something similar I am supposed to do on OS X, I would appreciate the advice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### Update

Here are the results to the [code that Alexander suggested running](http://pastebin.com/2zqF5XzZ)

> bool(false) 
>   string(69) "SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain"
>   string(0) ""

Comment: @Ohgodwhy the php_openssl.dll extension in the php.ini file is under "Windows Extensions" and the php info page says that OpenSSL is enabled. That lead me to believe I did not need to uncomment that line.

Comment: If you have CURL enabled, you could try [my little CURL SSL debugging script](http://pastebin.com/2zqF5XzZ), and post add the output from the page, and contents of `curlerror.txt` that should appear next to your script file.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara thanks for the tip. I should have mentioned that I must use the file_get_contents method because the code that is failing is part of the Bolt CMS framework. I only posted that one line since I have narrowed it down to that and it appears to be an issue with my XAMPP configuration.

Comment: Even if you can't use CURL in production, it may be able to reveal why it is failing to verify the certificate.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara good point! Here is the output of the script: _bool(false)
string(69) "SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain"
string(0) ""_

Comment: @chesjon How did you solve it?